# Chain a Dialog Fragment Result in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

How we can chain a dialog fragment within an `RxJava` chain and wait for its result (which button is clicked).

Something like:

```
buttonClickObservable.flatMap(v -> showDialogAndWaitForResponse()).subscribe(dialogResult -> doSomething());
```

Is this even possible? Could someone guide me here please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `RxBinding` library, you can do it like this:

```
buttonClickObservable
            .doOnNext(e -> showDialog())
            .flatMap(v -> dialogBtnClickObservable)
            .subscribe(clicked -> Log.d("TAG", "It's working!"));
```

**Edit:** Ok, turns out it's not that easy to observe the dialog's views using RxBinding. So, here's a complete example using `RxBinding` with a `PublishSubject`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;

    //here you can declare the Subject with the type
    //you're expecting as a result from the dialog
    public static final Subject<String> fragmentResultSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        RxView.clicks(btn)
                .doOnNext(e -> showDialog())
                .flatMap(v -> fragmentResultSubject)
                .subscribe(fragmentResult -> Log.d("TAG", fragmentResult));
    }

    private MyDialogFragment showDialog() {
        MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
        myDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "FRAG_TAG");

        return myDialogFragment;
    }


    public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        Button dialogBtn;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
            dialogBtn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.dialogBtn);
            dialogBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> fragmentResultSubject.onNext("Fragment btn clicked"));

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if thats the case then i better use rxbinding library always if im using rxjava for android?

Comment: It'll make your life much easier turning UI views into Observables

Comment: Hi agin, I don't quite understand how this works. Can you please give me some actual sample code please? It would really help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't it work with you? please update the question with the complete code you tried

Comment: I actually don't know where to get the "dialogBtnClickObservable" that is my problem. Could you guide me with that? I mean do you get it from the fragmentDialog? Something like myDialogFragment.getDialogBtnClickObservable()? Coz if thats the case then (correct me if I'm wrong here) Dialog fragment gets recreated when the screen is rotated so I get a different dialog fragment at that point and the object referenced in the "dialogBtnClickObservable" is the originalDialog fragment. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated the answer, check it out

Comment: Is that really the only way to do it? This looks to me that the fragment dialog needs to know where the PulishSubject is coming from. This binds the dialog fragment strictly to that Activity it was defined in. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: Of course it's not the only way, but it's one way to do it. You can create a constructor for the fragment passing in the subject to decouple it. I declared the fragment as inner class to simplify the example code

Comment: As far as I know you could not create a constructor for a Fragment. Anything you pass to it should be placed inside the setArguements method which accepts a Bundle. I believe Observable isnt a Parcelable or a Serializable for it to be passed inside a bundle. unless it is? Am I wrong again here? So far you've been a very big help. I really appreciate this.

Comment: No you can create a constructor in addition to a no arguments one, it's just not recommended because of the recreation scenario you mentioned earlier. Let's think how to solve this...

Comment: Yes I know you still could create a constructor but thats not the recommended way. Thats exactly the problem. If you pass in the constructor it will be lost when its recreated. We dont want that to happen. Could you Vote my question so we could find more help? Thank youu very much.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach:

## 1. Components

- Screen (Activity/Fragment) - This will display the dialog fragment
- DialogFragment - The dialog. Will publish updates about User's actions.
- DialogViewModel - holds the User's actions stream

### 2. Implementation

**SimpleActivity**

```
public class SimpleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SimpleDialogViewModel dialogViewModel;
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        dialogViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SimpleDialogViewModel.class);
        compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

        showDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Disposable disposable =
        dialogViewModel
                .actionStream()
                .subscribe(
                        result -> {

                            if (AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE == result) {
                                // User clicked yes
                            }

                            if (AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE == result) {
                                // User clicked no
                            }

                        }
                );
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        compositeDisposable.clear();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        SimpleDialogFragment dialogFragment = new SimpleDialogFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), SimpleDialogFragment.TAG);
    }
}
```

**SimpleDialogFragment**

```
public class SimpleDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "SimpleDialogFragment";

    private SimpleDialogViewModel dialogViewModel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dialogViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SimpleDialogViewModel.class);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_simple_message, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View btnYes = view.findViewById(R.id.yes);
        final View btnNo = view.findViewById(R.id.no);

        btnYes.setOnClickListener(v -> dialogViewModel.onClickYes());
        btnNo.setOnClickListener(v -> dialogViewModel.onClickNo());
    }
}
```

**SimpleDialogViewModel**

```
public class SimpleDialogViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private Subject<Integer> actionSubject;

    SimpleDialogViewModel() {
        actionSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    }

    public void onClickYes() {
        actionSubject.onNext(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    }

    public void onClickNo() {
        actionSubject.onNext(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    }

    public Observable<Integer> actionStream() {
        return actionSubject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats too much. At that point I don't think its worth it. If you gonna use viewmodel for that solution just do it the usual way. Its less code and much much easier than that.

Comment: I think it's a good solution if you need to decouple your Dialog from everything. It will be reusable out of the box.

Comment: My opinion is that, instead of just directing the call from fragnent to activity, you instead route the result to a viewmodel then the view model gets listened by the activity. Your solution added steps which the usual way doesnt need to. The benefits are very minimal in that solution and so the additional boiler plate aint worth it.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple options here: 1. you can call another ViewModel directly from the DialogFragment. This will make the dialog only usable for that use case. 2. Use this approach to decouple the dialog from everything when you need to reuse the dialog.